# Getting NPE for @Autowired bean when using custom composed annotation in JUnit Jupiter

Tags: java, spring-test, junit5

#### TransactionalIntegrationTest.java

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(locations = { "classpath:service.xml","classpath:data.xml" })
@Tag("1")
public @interface TransactionalIntegrationTest {}
```

#### MyTestTest .java

```
@TransactionalIntegrationTest
public class MyTestTest {
@Autowired
protected CreateUser createUser;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
createUser.createTimesheetUser(...)} --> NPE
}
```

Getting NullPointerException on `createUser`.

If I do not use the meta annotations, then it works fine.

#### MyTestTest.java

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(locations = { "classpath:service.xml","classpath:data.xml" })
@Tag("1")
public class MyTestTest {
@Autowired
protected CreateUser createUser;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws Exception {
createUser.createTimesheetUser(...)} --> works now
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the `@Retention` declaration which allows frameworks like Spring and JUnit to see the annotations at runtime.

Declaring your composed annotation as follows should work.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(locations = { "classpath:service.xml", "classpath:data.xml" })
@Tag("1")
public @interface TransactionalIntegrationTest {
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sam. It worked by adding @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME).Thank you for your feedback. It helped a lot after spending few days on trying to figure the listed issue.

Comment: Can you please explain me little bit about this annotation. It works but I am really not sure why? Or may be you can direct me to documentation.

Comment: I also noticed you added the following three annotations. Do I need them as my code works without it? I tried to read about them online but did not understand exactly what they do.@Target(ElementType.METHOD)@Documented@Inherited

Comment: Oops. I meant to use `@Target(ElementType.TYPE)`. That limits its application to classes, which you want since it doesn't make sense to use your custom annotation on methods, fields, etc.

Comment: `@Documented` and `@Inheritable` are optional. These are standard Java annotations. So just read their Javadoc and optionally a tutorial online about Java annotations for more information.